Reading patterns from config file to replace matching occurrence but AWK jumbles up and gsub fails to remove special characters and space
I am trying to replace a lot of patterns stored in list_file1 which match similar data in field 2 of data_file1 and then replace it completely from data_file1.
The data_file1 should match both upper case, lower case, or a combination of both upper and lower case patterns stored in list_file1.
The patterns stored in list_file1 will contain leading space, trailing space, and special characters. A few data examples are given below.
list_file1:
AIM TO CONVERT 
 AIM TO CONVERT 
(FAILED)
( FAILED) 
\REOCCUR

data_file1:
UR4289~Deal,( FAILED) Involved~ON654-L
PR4299~Invoc,(failed)closed~BG657-C
UR4980~ AIM TO CONVERT ,JUL51~NN655-V
UR4659~aim To convert -DISSOLVE~MV694-M

Expected output:
UR4289~Deal,Involved~ON654~L
PR4299~Invoc,closed~BG657~C
UR4980~,JUL51~NN655~V
UR4659~-DISSOLVE~MV694~M

Updating the question along with data as per ED's comment
Case 2 : We are trying to match on full "words" only For example if list_file1 contains part and men on separate lines while data_file1 contains apartment script should return actual line from data_file1 as list_file1 does not contain the string apartment
list_file1 (Below data contains leading/trailing and space in between strings as given below and [] denotes space:
[]FOO[] 
FOO[]    
[]FOOT[]   
FOOT[]
[]FOOT,
FOOT,[] 
[]FOOT[]FOO[] 
FOOT[]FOO[] 
[]FOOT[]FOO[]FOOT[]FOO[] 
FOOT[]FOO[]FOOT[]FOO[] 
[]BAR[] 
[]BAR
-BAR
/BAR 
(BAR) 
([]BAR) 

data_file1:(It can contain regex in lower or uppercase for the data defined in list_file1.)
 LR9289~Intex,clear~ON654-L
 UR4289~ FOOT FOO FOOT FOO Deal,FOO Involved~ON654-L
 PR4299~Invoc,FOO closed~BG657-C
 UR4980~ FOOT ,JUL51~NN655-V
 UR4659~FOOT FOO FOOT FOO DISSOLVE~MV694-M
 UR5896~-BAR WIN,foo Involved~ON654-L
 PR5897~Invoc,FOOT, closed~BG657-C
 UR5898~ (BAR),JUL51~NN655-V
 UR5899~( BAR)White-Lien~MV694-M
 UR5900~John bar Doe-Cat~MV694-M
 UR5901~KarlbAR Doe-HOD~MV694-M  

expected:Output_file:
LR9289~Intex,clear~ON654-L
UR4289~Deal,Involved~ON654-L
PR4299~Invoc,closed~BG657-C
UR4980~,JUL51~NN655-V
UR4659~DISSOLVE~MV694-M
UR5896~-BAR WIN,Involved~ON654-L
PR5897~Invoc,closed~BG657-C
UR5898~,JUL51~NN655-V
UR5899~White-Lien~MV694-M
UR5900~JohnDoe-Cat~MV694-M
UR5901~karlDoe-HOD~MV694-M


There are several issues with your example: there is no (FAILED) in list_file1 but in your expected output Invoc,(failed)closed is replaced with Invoc,closed; in the last fields of data_file1 all - are replaced with ~. Please edit your question and fix this. And while you're at it you could replace the word "pattern", which is ambiguous, with "string", "match" with "contains", and "replace it completely" with "delete".

Please also fix the replacement of - with ~ is the last field.

Look at the finale field in your inputs (e.g., ON654-L) and in your expected output (ON654~L). There is something wrong here.

Can you please read again your own question? In your expected output you wrote ON654~L. Please look at this part and only this part. Can you see the ~ (tilde) before L? According your shown input it should be - (dash), not ~ (tilde). If you don't see the difference between - (dash) and ~ (tilde), try maybe to zoom as much as you can. Same remark for the end of all other lines

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For your special case with GNU sed: sed -f <(tac list_file1 | sed -E 's|(.*)|s/\1//I|') data_file1

@cyrus This will treat all strings in list_file1 as regular expressions. Not what the OP want.

There are several issues with your code:

index($2,i) is case sensitive,
gsub(tolower(i),"",$0) substitutes the whole line instead of just field 2,
gsub(tolower(i),"",$0) treats tolower(i) as a regular expression, not as a literal string...

You could try:
awk -F'~' -v OFS='~' 'NR == FNR {a[tolower($0)] = length($0); next}
{
  for(i in a) {
    while(p = index(tolower($2), i)) {
      $2 = substr($2, 1, p - 1) substr($2, p + a[i])
    }
  }
  print
}' list_file1 data_file1

It is based on an array (a) where the index is a string to delete (like in your attempt) and the value is its length.
This will do what you asked for. But you apparently have strings in list_file1 that are sub-strings of others, and you apparently also want to delete the longest first. To achieve this there are at least 2 options:

If you can use GNU awk, use its sorting capabilities to force the order of for(i in a) to be the decreasing numeric order of values (that is, the length of the strings). We do this with the PROCINFO["sorted_in"] parameter. The following will delete the longest strings first:
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "~"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" }  
NR == FNR { a[tolower($0)] = length($0); next }
{
  for(i in a) {
    while(p = index(tolower($2), i)) {
      $2 = substr($2, 1, p - 1) substr($2, p + a[i])
    }
  }
  print
}' list_file1 data_file1


If GNU awk is not an option we can build a more complex data structure while parsing list_file1, such that we can list the strings in decreasing order of lengths:
awk -F'~' -v OFS='~' '
NR == FNR {
  len = length($0)
  cnt[len]++
  str[len,cnt[len]] = tolower($0)
  max = max < len ? len : max
  next
}
{
  for(i = max; i > 0; i--) {
    for(j = 1; j <= cnt[i]; j++) {
      while(p = index(tolower($2), str[i,j])) {
        $2 = substr($2, 1, p - 1) substr($2, p + i)
      }
    }
  }
  print
}' list_file1 data_file1




That's pretty good. Only one issue with additional whitespace in UR4980~ ,JUL51~NN655-V. This presents an awkward setup for awk. Since everything in list_file1 is to be treated as a Dynamic Regex special characters and escapes present a problem. I've haven't come up with a fix, so you got closer than I.

My understanding is that the content. of list_file1 must be treated as literal strings, not dynamic regex.

I think that is the correct understanding, but with that, it eliminates use of sub or the like. Your choice of substr was a good one.

Assumptions/understandings:

we are to perform case-insensitive matching but we are not to change the case of any data
if we find a string from list_file1 within the 2nd field (~ delimiter) from data_file1 then said string is to be removed from the field
if the removal of a string results in a new matching string then said new matching string is to be removed, too; this match/remove process is to be repeated until no more matches are found within a the 2nd field (from data_file1)
contents of list_file1 are literal strings and do not contain regex patterns
lines in list_file1 may contain leading/trailing white space and said white space is to be considered part of the string to be matched/removed
we are looking for word matches (eg, part will match on part,  part, and ~part~ but will not match on apartment)
OP has access to GNU awk

Issues/resolutions:

case-insensitive matching requires we either a) make use of tolower() (or toupper()) or b) make use of GNU awk's IGNORECASE setting; for this exercise we'll use IGNORECASE=1 to facilitate case-insensitive matching
many GNU awk string functions work with regexes; one exception is the index() function which works with strings; since the contents of list_file1 are literal strings we will want to use index() when looking for matches
OP's use of the gsub() function (which treats strings from list_file1 as regexes) is likely the cause for some incorrect results
since we need to match on exact words we'll need some logic to insure that an index() match is also a complete word match; since we're using GNU awk we'll go ahead and make use of the \W regex operator for matching on non-word characters (\W is basically shorthand for [^[:alnum:]_]); see GNU awk regex operators
we want to replace longer strings before replacing shorter strings so we'll need to keep track of the lengths of the strings from list_file1; we'll track strings and lengths via an awk array (lengths[]); to process these strings from longest to shortest we'll make use of GNU awk's predefined array scanning orders

Adding some additional test criteria to the mix:
$ cat list_file1
part
men
 foobar                                        # includes single trailing space
 football                                      # includes single trailing space
AIM TO CONVERT                                 # includes single trailing space
 AIM TO CONVERT                                # includes single trailing space
(FAILED)
( FAILED)                                      # includes single trailing space
\REOCCUR

$ cat data_file1
f1~one part flour~one part flour~f4
f1~apartment men women~f3
f1~men, can't live with them~f3
f1~1 2 3 foo football bar 4 5 6~ football ~f4  # ' foo football bar ' should be removed
f1~a b c foot foobar ball d e f~ foobar ~f4    # ' foot foobar ball ' should be removed
UR4289~Deal,( FAILED) Involved~ON654-L
PR4299~Invoc,(failed)closed~BG657-C
UR4980~ AIM TO CONVERT ,JUL51~NN655-V
UR4659~aim To convert -DISSOLVE~MV694-M
XYZ_123~first \REOCCUR last~more stuff

NOTE: comments do not exist in the actual files
One GNU awk idea:
awk '

#######
# to verify an exact word match we need to check the start and end of the match
#
# start: match at start of fld2
#  *OR*  first character of matching string is a non-word character
#  *OR*  last character before matching string is a non-word character
#
# end  : match at end of fld2
#  *OR*  last character of matching string is a non-word character
#  *OR*  1st character after matching string is a non-word character
#
# if we have a match for start *AND* end then we have an exact word match (rc=1)

function word_match() {
    rc=0                                             # default => no match

    if ( ( pos == 1 || substr(string,1,1) ~ /\W/ || substr(fld2,pos-1,1) ~ /\W/ ) \
         &&
         ( pos + len == length($2) || substr(string,len,1) ~ /\W/ || substr(fld2,pos+len,1) ~ /\W/ ) )
       rc=1                                          # we have an exact word match

    return rc
}

BEGIN   { FS = OFS = "~"
          IGNORECASE            = 1                  # enable case-insensitive matching
          PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"    # sort lengths[] array by numerical values in descending order
        }

FNR==NR { lengths[$0] = length($0)                   # 1st file: save strings and lengths
          next                                       # skip to next line of input
        }

        { buffer = ""                                # 2nd file: init variables
          found_match = 1                            # force initial pass through "while (found_match)" loop

          while (found_match) {                      # since removals may lead to new matches we need to loop until no new matches
                fld2 = $2                            # make copy of 2nd field
                buffer = ""                          # clear
                found_match = 0

                for (string in lengths) {            # loop through lengths[] array, longest strings first
                    len = lengths[string]

                    while (pos = index(fld2, string)) {
                          if (word_match()) {        # if we have an exact word match then remove the match and break out to "while (found_match)" loop
                             $2 = buffer substr(fld2, 1, pos-1) substr(fld2, pos + len)
                             buffer = ""
                             found_match = 1
                             break                   # 1st step to break out to topmost loop
                          }
                          else {                     # pos > 0 but word_match() failed; strip off and save leading contents, reset fld2 and repeat "while (pos = ...)" loop
                             buffer = buffer substr(fld2, 1, pos)
                             fld2 = substr(fld2, pos + 1)
                          }
                    }
                    if (length(buffer))              # if something in buffer then ...
                       $2 = buffer fld2              # rebuild field 
                    if (found_match)
                       break                         # 2nd step to break out to topmost loop
                }
          }
          print                                      # print current line
        }
' list_file1 data_file1

This generates:
f1~one  flour~one part flour~f4
f1~apartment  women~f3
f1~, can't live with them~f3
f1~1 2 34 5 6~ football ~f4
f1~a b cd e f~ foobar ~f4
UR4289~Deal,Involved~ON654-L
PR4299~Invoc,closed~BG657-C
UR4980~,JUL51~NN655-V
UR4659~-DISSOLVE~MV694-M
XYZ_123~first  last~more stuff


thanks for your time and a great explanation indeed. Need to quickly clarify around this sample  data set 1 2 3 foo football bar 4 5 6                 # ' only football' should be removed a b c foot foobar ball d e f #only foobar should be removed since football and foobar are part of list_file1 also we need to only modify field 2 of the whole line. Thanks again

removing ' football ' (leading/trailing space) will leave ' foobar ', but you're saying we do not want to go ahead and remove ' foobar ' from the new line even though it is from list_file1? I got caught up in the compound strings Ed was mentioning and completely missed the -F'~' and 'replace only 2nd field', let me think about this a bit ...

@Linnea I've updated the answer to only process the 2nd field; I've left the logic for rematching compound strings in place as I'm not sure I understand the requirement (though if compound strings can't occur in your real data then the code should still work, ie, a rematch won't be possible)


What am I missing here?

First argument to gsub is treated as regular expression and
AIM TO CONVERT 
 AIM TO CONVERT 
(FAILED)
( FAILED) 
\REOCCUR

does contain characters of special meaning e.g. brackets, consider that
echo "ABLE BAKER CHARLIE" | awk -v drop="(B)" '{gsub(drop,"",$0);print $0}'

gives output
ALE AKER CHARLIE

note that B were removed even though there is not bracket at at all in input.
I would use GNU AWK following way to work around for that, let file1.txt content be
 Able
(Baker)

note: there is leading space before Able and file2.txt content be
Able~Able~Able # no change - no leading space
Able~ Able~Able # remove
Able~ ABLE~Able # different case remove
Baker~Baker~Baker  # no change - no brackets
Baker~(Baker)~Baker  # remove
(Baker)~Baker~(Baker)  # no change - field different than 2nd

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~";IGNORECASE=1}FNR==NR{arr[gensub(/(.)/,"[\\1]","g")];next}{for(i in arr){gsub(i,"",$2)};print}' file1.txt file2.txt

gives output
Able~Able~Able # no change - no leading space
Able~~Able # remove
Able~~Able # different case remove
Baker~Baker~Baker  # no change - no brackets
Baker~~Baker  # remove
(Baker)~Baker~(Baker)  # no change - field different than 2nd

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that tilde is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS) and that it should work in case-insensitive manner (IGNORECASE). When processing first file I use gensub string function to envelope each character in square brackets, this is not strictly necessary for character without special meaning, but it is easier to envelop each character, this way (Baker) will be transformed into [(][B][a][k][e][r][)]. For all following files I use gsub at 2nd field with every key of array arr. Observe there is not need to use if as if there is not match then gsub is no-operation.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

thanks a bunch for writing a detailed explanation gives a lot of insight. While I got the context of placing variables in the list_file1 but there is a limitation to invoke exact strings for removal. In case we include only partial strings separately as stated above for Able (Baker) it would remove Able where ever exists in field $2 but ask is to only remove Able (Baker) when matches
